# Create GPO to remove desktop.ini in the public folder

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

We show all hidden files by default via GPO.  One of the things that we do also is remove the C:\users\%username%\desktop\desktop.ini and that is great, it works.  When I do this I also do the same for the public and remove: c:\users\public\desktop\desktop.ini file.  But when I do this, it doesn't work.  When I do it on a normal user account, it says access denied.  What kind of script can I run to grant access to this folder?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to remove desktop.ini?

Comment: It is actually never used again by the system.

Comment: It's used for setting certain properties of a folder and will be recreated whenever someone sets such a property for this folder. Question stands: why would you remove them?

Comment: Because once deleted it will not be recreated based on my experience.  And it will make the desktop look unorganized.

Comment: Only if you select to show system files :)

Comment: I found a better work around:
http://superuser.com/questions/257528/hide-desktop-ini-for-the-desktop-view-only-still-show-hidden-and-system-files